# how to check if an element of one list is in other list (different size of list)

Tags: python

```
a=[0,1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in range(4):
   if a[i] not in b:
     del a[i]
print a
```

I am getting this error
    IndexError: list index out of range
I don't know why ?

Comment: Your question doesn't match your code. Your question's title is asking how to _check_ if a list contains a value, but your code _deleting_ elements from a list and the error is completely unrelated to the membership testing. It's unclear what the code is intended to do, so we can't fix it for you. Please clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `range(4)` to `range(3)`.

This happens because when `i==0`, you remove the element from the list `a`, so the length of the list becomes `3` not `4`.

Comment: ...and what if you don't know how many elements will be deleted in the loop? What do you do then?

Comment: @Aran-Fey OP isn't asking for a generic solution. In the list he has given, that works.

Answer (score 0):

Properties of sets can be used for this type of problems.
For above problem, first we can convert both list to sets then take intersection between them.

```
set_a = set(a)
set_b = set(b)
common_elements_set = set_a.intersection(set_b)
common_elements_list = list(common_elements_set)
```